# How to access hotspot created on Linux(Ubuntu/ Mint)from android device?

Tags: 14.04, android

I am able to create hotspot(ad-hoc) and it is visible to other laptops and connects successfully but hotspot is not visible to android devices.

Comment: Android does not support by default ad-hoc wifi network

Answer (score 1):

Android **does not support** by default *ad-hoc wifi* network. For that to work, you need to install some third party app/utility that require most of the time that the android device is *rooted*.

So another option is to create a (software) **AP** (Access Point) on Ubuntu. But for that you need that your wifi card support it at the **driver level**. And few card support that. Check that with

```
$ sudo iw list
[...]
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point
```

You need the * AP line

Also if your card is not compatible with *nl80211*, the above command will output nothing. I don't know how to check the AP support in that case.

If your card support *AP mode*, then you can use https://github.com/oblique/create_ap which is a simple script that wrap around *hostapd*, *iptables*, ... and do the dirty work for you.

Install the dep:

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd iptables iw git
```

then run create_ap

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
sudo iw dev wlan0 disconnect
sudo ./create_ap -c 3 -w 2 wlan0 eth0 MyWifiAP mywifiappassword
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 ways to create wifi hotspot in Ubuntu:

- [Using Ap-hotspot, an open-source app from github](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-laptop-android/)
- [Using KDE connection editor](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/)
- [Using Unity’s Default Network Manager with a little hack](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/)

**Using Unity’s Default Network Manager with a little hack**

1. Disable WIFI and plug in an internet cable to your laptop so that your Ubuntu is connect to a wired internet and wireless is disabled.
2. Go to Network Icon on top panel -> Edit Connections …, then click the Add button in the pop-up window.
3. Choose Wi-Fi from the drop-down menu when you’re asked to choose a connection type
4. fill the wifi form
5. Go to Wi-Fi Security tab, select security type WPA & WPA2 Personal and set a password.
6. Go to IPv4 Settings tab, from Method drop-down box select Shared to other computers.

Full details [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/)

Comment: The article you refer to fails to mention that in order to create an AP, you need that the wifi card support that at the driver level. Check that with `iw list` under **Supported interface modes** for * AP. Also Ap-hostpsot is abondoned and the homepage states to use https://github.com/oblique/create_ap and I recommend it too.